# Choosing authentication flow for a web app with SPA at front end

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I'm developing an application that uses Microsoft Graph. It used to be an ASP .NET Framework web app using Razor pages but was almost completely converted to an Angular SPA with ASP .NET backend. Currently we're using Authorization Code Flow on the backend to log user in. Web API has session enabled so the client simply uses the same cookies as it did before when it was a Razor app.
But lately we've been thinking more and more about doing some Graph requests directly on the client and now I'm looking for a proper way to refactor our authentication to better satisfy the following requirements:

1. Log users in and process this on the server, so that the server can use delegated Graph permissions and call Graph API.
2. Provide a way for the client to call Graph directly without using our server.
3. Comply with current best practices for doing #2 on the client.
4. Work with third party cookies disabled when we're in an IFRAME (our app can be displayed and works with SharePoint online as well as AD logins).

I'm not sure what is the best way to share the access token that the servers gets for accessing the Graph or if it's event feasible from security point of view. Should I login with the server first and then use MSAL.js and login again with a login_hint (so hopefully without user entering his credentials two times)? Will appreciate any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I login with the server first and then use MSAL.js and login again with a login_hint (so hopefully without user entering his credentials two times)?

Yes, this is our recommended approach. You can use the MSAL.js `ssoSilent` to attempt to silently authenticate the user client-side, using the `login_hint` (or `sid`) from their existing session.

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer! What about the case when I'm displaying my app in a web part's IFRAME (sharepoint online), my app stops working with third-party cookies disabled so I guess I'll need to use a popup. However, loginPopup in msal only works for SPAs so the redirect must be processed by the client and I need it on the server. I like what MS Teams SDK does, it allows opening a popup with a URL of my choice, but unfortunately this library only works when there's a Teams context available. I really don't want to re-implement a bicycle and program popups for all browsers...

Comment: Right, ssoSilent will not work when 3p cookies are disabled. When using ssoSilent (and acquireTokenSilent), you should always have error handling logic that invokes an interactive method if you get back an interaction/login/consent required error. When your app is in an iframe, redirect will not work, so you will need to use a popup.

Comment: We are looking at ways to mitigate this, but for now, you will need to perform interaction.